# What does colls mean in the clojure documentation?

Tags: clojure

In the dos of mapcat you see **colls**. What does it mean?

```
clojure.core/mapcat
 [f]
 [f & colls]
```

Comment: Just a shorthand for "collections".

Comment: The "tricky" part here is also the `&`

Answer (score 2):

Colls means any number of collections. So mapcat can be called with

- only a function. In this case, it returns a transducer.
- with a function and a collection: it returns a sequence of concatenated results of calling the function on each element of the collection.
- with a function and multiple collections: similarly to the above, the result is the concatenation of results of invoking the function with first argument taken from the first collection, second arg from second coll, etc.

Comment: To give an example of the variadic `& colls`, if you use `mapcat` with a function that puts the arguments in a vector and three collections, you get: `(mapcat (fn [n1 n2 n3] [n1 n2 n3]) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) ;; => (1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9)`. This can also be written as `(mapcat (fn [& args] (vec args)) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) ;; => (1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9)`.

Comment: `colls` generally denotes a *sequence* of collections.